# разделитель числа

Tags: java

какой нужно использовать плагин в java чтобы выводилось число по разряду(например:   1234567 нужно чтоб выводилось 1 234 567)

Comment: что у вас на входе? число, строка, деньги ?

Answer (score 8):

Если Вам необходимо форматировать число в форму, в которой оно представлено с разделителями групп, можно воспользоваться [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) и [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) :

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
// вот тут устанавливаем разделитель он и так по умолчанию пробел, 
// но в этом примере я решил это сделать явно
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');     
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
// указываем сколько символов в группе
df.setGroupingSize(3);
System.out.println(df.format(12134567));
```

Выведет

```
12 134 567
```

Comment: Это же не плагин :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да к сожалению не плагин :(